# Are there any other Guardians?

Tags: golden-sun-the-lost-age

In *Golden Sun: The Lost Age* I've came across 2 optional bosses

- The first called Sentinel I encountered in the cave south of the Sea of Time Islet, the one the turtle takes you to and I had to use Teleport to reach deeper into the cave. It called itself the Guardian of Wind and I got the Catastrophe summon after I beat it
- The second called Star Magician I encountered in Treasure Island where I fought it and 4 balls which it kept summoning as I destroyed them. It called itself the Guardian of Water and I got the Azul summon after I beat it

Since there is 4 Elements in the game and the 2 summons I got majored with the Djinn of the element of their guardian I thought maybe there was 2 more that I may have missed somewhere which also guard summons.

So is there a Guardian of Fire and Guardian of Earth somewhere in *Golden Sun: The Lost Age*?

Comment: [Cue my obligatory grammar edit] Lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bosses you are looking for are:

### [Valukar](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Valukar)

This boss is the Guardian of Fire, whom protects the Summon [Daedelus](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Daedalus). This boss can be found in the Yampi Desert, near Alhafra.

### [Dullahan](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Dullahan)

This is the Guardian of Earth, and protects the Summon [Iris](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Iris). This boss is found in the Anemos Sanctum, near Contigo.

Additionally, there is a grand total of [13 multi-elemental Summons](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Summon_sequence#In_Golden_Sun:_The_Lost_Age) throughout the game that can be found (not including the 4 guarded Summons):

- Zagan (1 Venus, 1 Mars)
- Megaera (1 Mars, 1 Jupiter)
- Flora (1 Venus, 2 Jupiter)
- Moloch (2 Mercury, 1 Jupiter)
- Ulysses (2 Mars, 2 Mercury)
- Haures (3 Venus, 2 Mars)
- Eclipse (3 Jupiter, 2 Mercury)
- Coatlicue (3 Jupiter, 3 Mercury)
- Charon (8 Venus, 2 Jupiter)

Interestingly, [Charon](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Charon) is actually the Ultimate Venus Summon, not Iris (Ultimate Mars Summon), which is the Summon guarded by the boss in Anemos Sanctum, but can be found near the entrance of the Anemos Sanctum. The only pre-requisite is that you have all 72 Djinni to access the Sanctum, including all 28 from the original *Golden Sun*. This does seem a bit odd, since Daedelus is not actually an "Ultimate Summon".

Comment: arf, you were faster.. +1

Comment: Beat me to the answer as well, and also gave the other unlockable summons. Might be worth noting that the Anemos Inner Sanctum requires all 72 djinn to access, and that Dullahan is tougher than the end-of-game boss.

Answer (score 3):

According to Golden Age's Wikia, there are four superbosses, optional, in the game.

> Sentinel is one of four "superbosses" located throughout Weyard in The
>   Lost Age, the others being Valukar, Star Magician, and Dullahan. All
>   of these bosses fight using unique battling setups and are very tough.

([From Sentinel page](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Sentinel))

The two other bosses you haven't defeated yet are :

- [Valukar](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Valukar) : probably the Guardian if Fire, as it is stated:

> The name "Valukar" may be based on Valaraukar, which translates to
>   "demons of might", and was an alternative name for the Balrog race in
>   Tolkien's mythos. This is further supported by Valukar's appearance as
>   a red, winged demon associated with fire.

It is located at the end of the optional dungeon Yampi Desert Cave.

- [Dullahan](http://goldensun.wikia.com/wiki/Dullahan) : located at the end of the optional dungeon Anemos Inner Sanctum. The Wikia also states that it will give you the most powerful summon sequence, while being the hardest boss to defeat.

There's no etymology for that name, so I can't be sure it is the Guardian of Earth. There is no other super boss though.

All provided links to Wikia articles contains all details concerning their arsenal, skills and characteristics, but I thought it would have been irrelevant here.